# Can I buy patent for a specific gesture that I have used for specific purpose in google glass app?

Tags: patentability, process, patent-services

I am new to patents and I was wondering that can I buy patent for a specific gesture used for a specific purpose in Google glass.
The thing is that I have implemented something in one of my glass apps and i think it would be copied by other developers so I want to stop that.

Can anyone guide me? I live in Asia and I don't know how to buy a patent and whether it will be valid worldwide or not?

Comment: Sheraz, is it your intention to "buy" an existing patent of a third party or to apply for a patent on something you have developed?

Comment: @Phoenix88 Its a feature that i developed on Google glass. Like i used a specific gesture for specific purpose and i don't want anyone to copy it :)

Answer (score 1):

Sheraz, patents are geographic in nature.  So, a US patent, for example, only provides the owner with exclusionary rights in the US.

I recommend you get in contact with a local patent attorney to discuss.  Many patents have been issued for gestures in the context of touchscreens, trackpads and the like.  See ==> http://io9.com/10-physical-gestures-that-have-been-patented-1251848412